# Self creating modules for asynchronous import

Tags: python, dictionary, python-module

I have a question regarding self-creating modules. I am writing a very dynamic script that, based on a user key and a key dictionary, generates a function including a dictionary.

My question has to do with best practices for self-creating modules. Obviously I can open and write to a .py file, but what is the best format for doing so? I generated large SQL query documents using the same format, even though I know it's prone to injection. I work in a very controlled environment and I have a string validation statements so I'm not too worried.

I know the same works for modules, but I'd really not like to get myself in the bad habit of coding this way.

```
with open('keystruct.py', 'w+') as KeyStruct:
    KeyStruct.write('''
def KeyAssignments(referencekey):''')
    KeyStruct.write('''
    ReferenceKey = {}'''.format(CharacterKeyList)) # Ignore indentation for this line.
    print(CharacterKeyList)
```

No time better than the present to learn how to do things correctly, eh?

Also, would if the above is considered "okay", would it be generally acceptable to have a single dictionary with 50+ objects defined on a single line if it's merely used for self-reference?

The output of the above statement is this:

```
...    
ReferenceKey = ['A = 0', 'B = 1', 'C = 2', 'D = 3', 'E = 4', 'F = 5', 'G = 6', 'H = 7', 'I = 8', 'J = 9', 'K = 10', 'L = 11', 'M = 12', 'N = 13', 'O = 14', 'P = 15', 'Q = 16', 'R = 17', 'S = 18', 'T = 19', 'U = 20', 'V = 21', 'W = 22', 'X = 23', 'Y = 24', 'Z = 25', 'a = 26', 'b = 27', 'c = 28', 'd = 29', 'e = 30', 'f = 31', 'g = 32', 'h = 33', 'i = 34', 'j = 35', 'k = 36', 'l = 37', 'm = 38', 'n = 39', 'o = 40', 'p = 41', 'q = 42', 'r = 43', 's = 44', 't = 45', 'u = 46', 'v = 47', 'w = 48', 'x = 49', 'y = 50', 'z = 51', '0 = 52', '1 = 53', '2 = 54', '3 = 55', '4 = 56', '5 = 57', '6 = 58', '7 = 59', '8 = 60', '9 = 61']
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to dynamically generate code, try separating the functionality from the data.  Dump the data to something like JSON, then use a function factory or a class to load and use the various configurations you create.